# PowerShell. Get all processes where name starts with C (capital C)

Tags: powershell

How to get process names in PowerShell which start only with a capital letter (i.e. C or B)?
The command:
`Get-Process -Name "C*"`
returns all processes starting with "c" regardless capital it is or small.

Answer (score 2):

The filtering performed by the `-Name` parameter isn't case-sensitive, use `Where-Object` to filter the output further:

```
Get-Process -Name C* |Where-Object Name -clike 'C*'
```

The `c` in front of `like` makes it case-sensitive